# XSL Manual Sorting based on Number

Tags: html, xml, sorting, xslt

I'm working on XML 1.0 trying to figure out a way to sort XML data based on a number that I specify.

The html currently output something like this:

```
Dog Name    Dog Mood
Sally       Sad
Rachel      In Heaven
Susie       Crying
April       Happy
Suvvannah   Happy
```

What I'm trying to achieve is:

```
Dog Name    Dog Mood
Rachel      In Heaven
Suvvannah   Happy
April       Happy
Susie       Crying
Sally       Sad
```

There is not a particular order to sort from, but rather an order that I want to specify. I want to be able to sort manually base on `<trace-type>` in the following xml data (please note that this data cannot be changed, it's auto generated):

```
<trace-conf>
    <trace-item>
        <trace-type>1</trace-type>
        <trace-level>1</trace-level>
    </trace-item>
    <trace-item>
        <trace-type>2</trace-type>
        <trace-level>4</trace-level>
    </trace-item>
    <trace-item>
        <trace-type>3</trace-type>
        <trace-level>0</trace-level>
    </trace-item>
    <trace-item>
        <trace-type>4</trace-type>
        <trace-level>3</trace-level>
    </trace-item>
    <trace-item>
        <trace-type>5</trace-type>
        <trace-level>3</trace-level>
    </trace-item>
</trace-conf>
```

The numerical values from `<trace-type>` and `<trace-level>` will match the values from this other xml data file. The `<trace-type>NUMBER</trace-type>` value matches to the `<key name="Name">` value and `<trace-level>NUMBER</trace-level>` value matches to the `<key name="Mood">` value.

```
<key name="Mood">
    <items>
        <item name="0">Crying</item>
        <item name="1">Sad</item>
        <item name="2">Okay</item>
        <item name="3">Happy</item>
        <item name="4">In Heaven</item>
    </items>
</key>

<key name="Name">
    <items>
        <item name="1">Sally</item>
        <item name="2">Rachel</item>
        <item name="3">Susie</item>
        <item name="4">April</item>
        <item name="5">Suvannah</item>
    </items>
</key>
```

What I have for my XSL part that is relevant is:

```
<xsl:template match="'Doggy Log'">
    <h5><xsl:value-of select="'Doggy Log'"/></h5>
    <table summary="Doggy Log">
        <tr>
            <th><xsl:call-template name="getResource"><xsl:with-param name="resID" select="'Dog Name'"/></xsl:call-template></th>
            <th><xsl:call-template name="getResource"><xsl:with-param name="resID" select="'Dog Mood'"/></xsl:call-template></th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="trace-item">
            <tr>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="$KEY[@name = 'Name']/items/item[@name = current()/trace-type]"/></td>

                <td><xsl:value-of select="$KEY[@name = 'Mood']/items/item[@name = current()/trace-level]"/></td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</xsl:template>
```

I'm having trouble with the ability to display the `<trace-type>` by the order I want to specify.

For example, the above "trying to achieve" outcome should be resulted from `<trace-type>` order: 2, 5, 4, 3, 1, which will be Rachel, Suvvannah, April, Susie, Sally. Instead I'm getting the order that is placed in the xml data: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, which will be Sally, Rachel, Susie, April, Suvvannah. How do I go about sorting it manually to the way I need it to display?

I was thinking it would work with something like this, but it didn't:

`<xsl:sort select="trace-type" data-type="number" order="'2' '5' '4' '1'"/>`

And I'm sure a loop can be used to shorten the version than to have each and individual value displayed ie.

```
            <tr><td><xsl:value-of select="$KEY[@name = 'Name']/items/item[@name = current()/trace-item/trace-type = 1]"/></td></tr>
            <tr><td><xsl:value-of select="$KEY[@name = 'Name']/items/item[@name = current()/trace-item/trace-type = 2]"/></td></tr>
            <tr><td><xsl:value-of select="$KEY[@name = 'Name']/items/item[@name = current()/trace-item/trace-type = 3]"/></td></tr>
            <tr><td><xsl:value-of select="$KEY[@name = 'Name']/items/item[@name = current()/trace-item/trace-type = 6]"/></td></tr>
            <tr><td><xsl:value-of select="$KEY[@name = 'Name']/items/item[@name = current()/trace-item/trace-type = 4]"/></td></tr>
            <tr><td><xsl:value-of select="$KEY[@name = 'Name']/items/item[@name = current()/trace-item/trace-type = 5]"/></td></tr>
```

etc.. Since this question is shortened, the actual data has 40 some values to match.

Comment: This is very confusing. I *think* what you're trying to do is sort by a value looked up from the `<trace-conf>` element? If so, please explain how the "key items" (dogs, moods) are supposed to match up with the "trace-items". Also, where is the "manual" part in all of this?

Comment: I tried to clarify again. `<trace-conf>` element would match with the `<item name="NUMBER">` to get the name of the Dog and the mood of the dog. Various "manual" ways of displaying the data didn't work that I have attached, either by error, or just redundancy.

Comment: Shouldn't it be the other way round? That each dog would get the matching trace-level and then the list of dogs would be sorted by that?

Comment: Tim had the right idea on sort order. It's basically sorting in any order I would want, something like he mentioned with `<xsl:sort select="string-length(substring-before('25431', trace-type))" />` but the order can also be 43512 or 12345 or any other combinations that the user chooses. But it's still not working quite right.

Comment: I believe it would be more robust to enter the values in a *structured* manner, so that it will hold for *any* number of values you may need in the future. My answer shows one such way (actually, I copied it from you). I could have made it a bit simpler - only you said earlier that "this data cannot be changed, it's auto generated".

Comment: Yeah the data cannot be changed, since it is auto generated. The values also won't be changed in the future. I don't understand why the sort won't sort correctly. Thinking there may be another way to sort manually by selection of numbers in sequence?

Comment: I am afraid I have lost track of what this is about (assuming I had it in the first place...). I have edited my answer to make it as simple as possible. Hopefully it can be helpful - if not to you, perhaps to someone else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little bit crude, but this sort expression should do it....

```
<xsl:sort 
     select="string-length(substring-before('25431', trace-type))" 
     data-type="number" />
```

Of course, this will only work if all your **trace_type** values are single-digit. If you want to cope with multiple digits values, then it becomes a little more cruder.

```
<xsl:sort 
     select="string-length(substring-before('#2#5#4#3#1#', concat('#', trace-type, '#')))" 
      data-type="number" />
```

Comment: Oh, this is great. Now I don't understand the question AND the answer. Where is the sequence "25431" coming from?

Comment: This is getting close. "25431" is a order that I picked. I tried putting this to use for 39 numbers, and for the most part, the sorting is correct, except for every 4-7 digits, a random value would be misplaced. I changed it to printing out numbers to make reading easier. I put #1#2#3#6#4#5#7#8#9#10# to begin with, and it outputted 1 11 12 13 14 15 16.. and so on till the end where it finishes with 35 36 37 38 39 5 7 8 9 10 2 3 6 4. Any idea why?

Comment: `#1#2#3#6#4#5#7#8#9#10#11#12#13#36#37#39#14#15#16#17#18#19#20#21#22#23#24#25#26#27#28#29#30#35#31#32#33#34#38#` would display 1, 5, 34, 38, 7, 8, 9, 10, 2, 11, 12, 13, 36, 37, 39, 14, 3, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 6, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 4, 28, 29, 30, 35, 31, 32, 33

Comment: My bad. I missed out specifying ` data-type="number" ` in the sort statement. I've edited my answer to show this now.

Comment: Works perfect! I looked at it again and didn't see your comment, thought I forgot the `data-type="number"` part myself. Thank you for your help! It works magically delicious!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simplified situation, which you should hopefully be able to adapt to your own. Given the following XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <objects>
        <object value="5">Echo</object>
        <object value="1">Alpha</object>
        <object value="2">Bravo</object>
        <object value="3">Charlie</object>
        <object value="4">Delta</object>
    </objects>

    <sortorder>
            <value rank="1">2</value>
            <value rank="2">5</value>
            <value rank="3">4</value>
            <value rank="4">3</value>
            <value rank="5">1</value>
    </sortorder>
</root>
```

applying the following stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="lookup" match="sortorder/value" use="." />

<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<table>
<xsl:for-each select="root/objects/object">
<xsl:sort select="key('lookup', @value)/@rank" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
    <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
    </tr>   
</xsl:for-each>
</table>
</html>
</xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will return:

```
Bravo
Echo
Delta
Charlie
Alpha
```

which matches the following logic:

```
Bravo   2 --> 1
Echo    5 --> 2
Delta   4 --> 3
Charlie 3 --> 4
Alpha   1 --> 5
```

Note that the sort order could be in another document, even in the stylesheet itself.